# Updating test case as PASS/FAIL in TFS using java SDK

Tags: java, tfs, sdk

How to update a test case as PASS/FAIL in TFS given the test case ID and suite ID using java SDK? I have searched and found out I need to use the rest API. But could anyone share the code or share a link from where I can learn how to use it? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I have updated a more detail answer for your reference, please kindly review it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After go through the latest version of JAVA SDK (*[Download page for TEE 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47727)*),  there's no related method and API by using Java SDK  to modify tests and update the test results in TFS.

---

To use  **Rest Api** for updating Test Case results. You need to use
   [Update test results for a test run](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results)

You could call  TFS rest API  using **postman** for a test. Sample request fail a case as below:

```
PATCH https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/Defaultcollection/Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC/_apis/test/runs/26/results?api-version=3.0-preview
```

*Content-Type: application/json*

```
[
  {
    "id": 100000,
    "state": "Completed",
    "outcome": {
          enum { Failed}

  },

]
```

If you haven't already with Rest API, look at the information on [getting started](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/rest/basics)  with these APIs.

---

To use REST API to connect to TFS from Java code, you need to use **HttpClient**

*A sample list git repos using Java Client code call rest api:*

```
private void getRequest() throws Exception {
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
            new NTCredentials("user", "password", "workstation", "domain"));

    HttpHost target = new HttpHost("tfs.web.com", 8080, "http");

    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("/tfs/CollectionName/ProjectName/_apis/git/repositories/repo-name");
    CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(target, httpget, context);
    try {
        HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        response1.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I couldn't get the rest endpoints for TFS so I created a console application in C# and called it in java using the exe of the c# application. So all is well now :) Thanks for all your help though.